# Avoid trailing comma in array and object literals in $.expr[':'] - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sonarqube

I have code which is giving error on sonar testing:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
            "in-viewport": function(a) {
                return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : $('voya-header').height()});
            },
        })
```

Not sure why it is giving issue while testing but its working fine in all browser and device.

Issue is `$.expr[':']**,**

if i am removing this comma then code stop working properly.
please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Why would you remove that comma?

Comment: its giving error in sonarqube testing.. that COMMA is giving error

Answer (score 2):

I may not be able to clear the fact about this as in my language. But you must remove the last comma.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
            "in-viewport": function(a) {
                return $.inviewport(a, {threshold : $('voya-header').height()});
            },//remove comma from here
        })
```

As it's not exactly the trailing comma. The trailing comma would be like this:

```
var obj = {
  prop1: value1,
  prop2: value2,//trailing comma
}
```

But in your case:

```
$.extend(option1,option2,) //should not be used like this
//last comma is not trailing comma but misleading to use next option
```